# How to change my "channels & interests" on an Android phone?

Tags: google, google-discover

I have an Android phone and get some news based on my "channels & interests" when I swipe from the main Home Screen to the left. How can I add a new topic to these "channels & interests"?

I found [this site](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2819496) which does not really help. In *Step 2: Choose what updates you get* it does not explain how to **add** a new topic. I only can view some list I can choose from.

Is there any way to really implicitly, directly and clearly add a new topic to that list?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [it isn't possible](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/124748317/what-are-channels-and-interests?hl=en&msgid=125565510) as mentioned in Google forums (incidentally, three days ago). A workaround was also suggested

> .... there is **no manual way so no way to write in an actual topic to that channel & interest area**. If you look up machine learning or AI enough it might then start to show in that area. Something else I would recommend you do is anytime you find a card in Google Discover that you would want to go back to at some point, click on the heart symbol which means like and then you can find it at https://www.google.com/search/contributions/reactions

(Emphasis supplied)